# Let $A$ be an $m \times n$ matrix where $m \neq n$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Which of the statement is/are always true?

(I) If $v$ is orthogonal to the row space of $A$, then $v$ is in the nullspace of $A$.

(II) The set of all vectors orthogonal to the column space of $A$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R^n}$.

I have put (II) to be the statement that are always true, but I'm doubting my own answer. Would appreciate if anyone can give me some guidance/hints, thanks!

Comment: (I) is essentially an exercise for understanding the following concepts:

 - row space of $A$;
 - a vector $v$ being orthogonal to a vector space;
 - null space of $A$.

Simply writing down the definitions of phrases above would get you started.

Comment: "I have put (II) to be the statement that are always true, but I'm doubting my own answer." What is it?

Answer (score 0):

If $v$ is orthogonal to the row of $A$ hence, its dot product with each row of $A$ is zero. Hence, $A v = 0$. It means $v$ is in the null space of $A$. Hence, it is true always.

For the second part, in the same manner of the first case, if $x$ is a member of vectors which are orthogonal to the columns of $A$, $A^T x = 0$. As $A^T$ is $n \times m$, Hence, $x$ is null space of $A^T$, and it is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^m$. In this case, if $m > n$, we cannot say it is true always.

Comment: What do you mean "it could be subspace... if $m>n$"?  No matter whether $m>n$ or $m<n$ you cannot regard a set of vectors in $\mathbb R^m$ as a subspace of $\mathbb R^n$.

Comment: @ErickWong it's clarified.

Comment: I still don't understand why you choose to qualify this with "$m>n$".  How is it any different when $m<n$?